# AWS amplify deploy failure due to aws-exports

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy my reactJs app to Amplify. I have my Github connected to Amplify. During deployment it shows the following error at Build step:

```
2020-01-07T19:35:22.127Z [INFO]: Failed to compile.
2020-01-07T19:35:22.129Z [INFO]: ./src/index.js
                                 Cannot find file './aws-exports' in './src'.
2020-01-07T19:35:22.149Z [WARNING]: error Command failed with exit code 1.
2020-01-07T19:35:22.150Z [INFO]: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2020-01-07T19:35:22.155Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2020-01-07T19:35:22.239Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2020-01-07T19:35:22.239Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
```

This happens because `.gitignore` ignores aws-exports. 
Can someone please tell me what's the solution to this problem without committing aws-exports?

Comment: If you are not able to find aws-exports, try to use ( amplify pull ) https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/186

Answer (score 36):

I have experienced the same problem in my first build.

The Amplify documentation is not specific about how you should maintain your builds when using the Amplify Console, but the routine that worked for me was:

You generate your `aws-exports` file when you run a successful `amplify push` command.

> **aws-exports.js file**
> This file is generated only for JavaScript
> projects. It contains the consolidated outputs from all the categories
> and is placed under the src directory that the user (the developer)
> specified during the init process. It is updated after each successful
> execution of the amplify push command, that has created or updated the
> cloud resources.

Based on that I updated my configuration in the Amplify console to also deploy my backend. You can learn how to configure your own at  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html

```
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

After the backend build is done the file is generated for my next job which is the frontend build that consumes the `aws-exports` file.

Note: If you're using eslint you can have a problem with the file output format. You can add a `eslint --fix` command in your frontend `preBuild`

Update: As [lucdenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581993/lucdenz) mentioned, you also need to setup a [service role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/how-to-service-role-amplify-console.html)

Sources I used:

- https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/usage#aws-exportsjs-file

Comment: I solved the problem by completely removing any code that uses aws-exports, I realized I didn't actually need to import that file.

Comment: Yeah, if you're not using any backend from amplify this is for sure the best way for doing it. If you come to add any backend dependencies than it will come to this.

Comment: I am fading thé sale thing. I added Auth to my project. I use a plugin file in which I need to load Cognito user before app mounting. Since then, when I push the code to git. The amplify console run the build which failed because the file is missing. Any idea?

Comment: Excellent answer -- that helped me, thank you.  Just to add, if you don't yet have a ServiceRole for the back end, you'll need to add one for this to work.

Comment: `amplifyPush --simple` is documented here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html#frontend-with-backend.

Comment: Needs a service role as well. Doc can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/how-to-service-role-amplify-console.html

Comment: tried this but build failed with message "Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete" anybody else got this?

Comment: @Ricky this error you're getting is probably due to a failed backend deploy. Check your cloudFormation console for any error's related to your project stack.

Comment: Sources link seems to be invalid now :(. Are there more references on this?

Comment: So following this, I hit a few different issues with backend build: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6117 (version mismatch locally and remotely), https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5931 (bug with recent version of cli?), now trying to deal with https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5791 and wishing I can just push it manually, but apparently it's not an option https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/956

Comment: Since this issue has been a lot discussed and seeing @Stvad comments I'll take some time to update the answer, thank you for the collaboration.

Comment: Note that this is only if you build with AWS, in my case on Netlify, `amplifyPush --simple` is not available. [According to this GitHub comment](https://github.com/aws-amplify/docs/issues/503#issuecomment-686752095), `aws-exports.js` does NOT contain sensitive data. The reason it's in `.gitignore` is that it'll apply the same config across all your environments.

Comment: Renaming aws-exports.js -> aws-exports.ts also worked.